# Warning using rxwebvalidator mixing async validators

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using library 'rxwebvalidator' from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rxweb/reactive-form-validators

Everything is working fine, but it showing warning in console. Here is the warning

> It looks like you're constructing using a FormControl with both an
> options argument and an   async validators argument. Mixing these
> arguments will cause your async validators to be dropped.   You should
> either put all your validators in the options object, or in separate
> validators   arguments. For example:
>
> // Using validators arguments   fc = new FormControl(42,
> Validators.required, myAsyncValidator);
>
> // Using AbstractControlOptions   fc = new FormControl(42,
> {validators: Validators.required, asyncValidators: myAV});
>
> // Do NOT mix them: async validators will be dropped!   fc = new
> FormControl(42, {validators: Validators.required}, /* Oops! */
> myAsyncValidator);

I just put the model

```
export class QnaList {
@required()
@minLength({value: 5})
@maxLength({value: 50})
question: string;

@required()
@minLength({value: 10})
@maxLength({value: 100})
answer: string;
```

}

And initialize it

```
        let qnaList = new QnaList();
    this.qnaForm = this.fb.formGroup(qnaList, new FormBuilderConfiguration({
        baseAbstractControlOptions: {
            answer: {
                updateOn: 'blur'
            },
        },
    }))
```

How to remove or suppress this warning?
I'm using angular 14 and rxwebvalidator 2.1.7

Comment: Same error here. Couldn't find a solution. Exactly same versions of Angular and rxwebvalidator.

Comment: I also have this problem and I can't solve it

Comment: I think this issue was fixed according to this closed issue on GitHub https://github.com/rxweb/rxweb/issues/612 although there doesn't appear to be any new releases. Hoping they put out a release soon!